# The New boston tut56 android .. app crashes when i click on anything

Tags: java, android, adt

I am on the 56th video on the android dev series on the new boston. I have no errors in my problems tab on the adt. the app starts up but when i go to click on any of the menu items it crashes. there is lots of different java files and xml on the app so i dont know where the problem is? any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Post your code and the crash log from your logcat.

Comment: check if u have refered ur xml ui controls properly in java code